# How can I build a dynamic parameter list for mail command in bash linux?

Tags: linux, centos7

I am trying to send a mail with a file names in the message body from my terminal to my gmail account. I am using mail command to do it. My requirement is that I should dynamically update the file names in the message body as the code run...I no need to send as an attachment. I am using centos7.

Below is my script:

```
v_cfg_email_adresse_to="abc@gmail.com"
v_cfg_email_subject="Report from December 2016"
v_tmp_email_text_name="Message Body"

v_email_main_file="test3.sh"
v_tmp_path="/home/centos/rr/"

if [ ! -z "${v_email_main_file}" ]; then
  v_mailx_parameters+=( -a "${v_tmp_path}${v_email_main_file}" )
fi
v_mail_x_parameters+=( -s "${v_cfg_email_subject}" )
v_mail_x_parameters+=( "${v_cfg_email_adresse_to}" )

printf '/binmailx %s < %s\n' "${v_mail_x_parameters[*]}" "${v_tmp_email_text_name}"
/bin/mailx "${v_mailx_parameters[@]}" < "${v_email_main_file}"
```

If the code is not correct..Please help me..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you properly configured your system so that mail is sent and actually delivered vs sending /dev/null as spam or bouncing... ?

Comment: Use `ls -l /var/spool/mail/$(whoami)` to see if the mail is stuck on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of above code i just redirected my output in the mail command using > .I works fine!!